# How to avoid duplicate symbols between xcodeproject and static library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries

I have an Main.xcodeproj with a file named **Test.h** and **Test.m** and I have linked  a static library within that project with files of same names(Test.h, Test.m). I am getting the error of duplicate symbols because Test.h and Test.m is common in both static library and xcode project that include the library. If I refactor file to rename it by refactor> rename, in the library or in the proejct itself it compiles fine.

How can I avoid these errors without changing the files by refactor> renaming them?

here is the log **libTest.a** is the static Library

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Test in:
 /Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Master-fmkociodeqhkyofkkwdmsymbykyh/Build/Intermediates/Master.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Master.build/Objects-normal/i386/Test.o
 /Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Master-fmkociodeqhkyofkkwdmsymbykyh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libTest.a(Test.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Test in:
 /Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Master-fmkociodeqhkyofkkwdmsymbykyh/Build/Intermediates/Master.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Master.build/Objects-normal/i386/Test.o
 /Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Master-fmkociodeqhkyofkkwdmsymbykyh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libTest.a(Test.o)
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense as the filenames are not symbols.  Please show the complete linker error message.

Comment: updated with the logs

Comment: So you have two duplicate symbols; the `Test` and `abc` classes.  You cannot have duplicate symbols and it's got nothing to do with the filenames, so the statement "If I change the names of the file inthe library it compiles fine" cannot be true.

Comment: It has to do with the names. if I remove the files either from project or from the library I no longer get the error. Also by renaming the file I mean that change the whole file with Refactor> Rename. So If I refactor and rename the file in xcodeproject or library I no longer get the error

Comment: Well that makes more sense; a refactor is more than a rename and you should edit your question to correct that.  However what do you want to achieve?  You cannot have different classes with the same names.

Comment: so one cannot have classes with the same name, in the static library and and the project that includes that library?

Comment: No, you can't.  A static library is nothing special; just a collection of object files.

Comment: OK If I don't use static library, is there any way to have an xcodeproject with a subproject such that both of them have two files with the same name but different code inside those files?

Comment: No, that's not possible.